# Maven multithreaded build problems

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, junit4, hamcrest

I've inherited a project that uses maven 3.6.2.  It compiles fine every time without fail when I do a

```
 mvn clean install
```

However, when I try to speed up the builds and make them multhreaded

```
mvn -T C1 clean install
```

I get all kinds of things that don't make sense.  At first I thought it was a dependency problem, but that doesn't seem to be it, i don't think.

Here's a pom file:

```
<project
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>project-components-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0.0_EXPERIMENTAL-VERSION</version>
    <name>project-hadoop</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-release-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0.0_EXPERIMENTAL-VERSION</version>
        <relativePath>../../project-core/project-release-dependencies</relativeP
ath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

junit and hamcrest are ALSO listed as "test" dependencies in the parent poms.

When I build multithreaded, I sometimes get

```
15:54:06  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project project-hadoop: There are test failures.
15:54:06  [ERROR] 
15:54:06  [ERROR] Please refer to [directory]/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
15:54:06  [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
15:54:06  [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
15:54:06  [ERROR] org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
15:54:06  [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
15:54:06  [ERROR] org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
```

The contents of the dump file are:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.getConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  the pom file SAYS junit (and hamcrest) are dependencies.  and this works SOMETIMES.it works fine single threaded.  How stable is the multithreaded stuff in maven?

More importantly, what am i missing?  shouldn't it be able to find the RunListener?

Comment: Does it build without doing the `install` part? (you have to delete the local cache first)...? via `mvn -T 3 clean verify`? Based on `<relativePath>../../project-core/project-release-dependencies</relativePath>` this looks like you are not calling from the root of the project?

Comment: Intersting.  Yes!  `mvn verify` DOES consistently work, but mvn install does NOT (failing differently each time).. I am calling `mvn` from the root of the project.  The pom hierarchy does not match the directory hierarchy, thats why I have the`<relativePath>`  stuff in there, to go up two and down one for example. Could that be my issue? (I also note that if i do NOT do `mvn install`, then all my other poms in this project can't find each other without the `<relativePath>` stuff.)

Comment: If you have to use `mvn install` before you can use `mvn -T3 clean verify` you have wrong/missing dependencies in your build or `mvn -T3 clean verify` (with clean cache) does not work but `mvn -T3 clean install` ...is also a symptom .. There are other issues in your build which very hard to identify ..having a link to the project would help here.